# Getting this error "class org.slf4j.MDC tried to access private field org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder.SINGLETON"

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-flink, slf4j

I am starting a spring boot application which listens to kafka topic and processes them with Apache flink. Basically, i am migrating the existing application from Java 8 to 11. I made the required changes and getting this error while starting the application.

{"timestamp":"2020-07-28T17:21:56,511Z","level":"ERROR","thread":"flink-metrics-2","message":"FATAL: Thread 'flink-metrics-2' produced an uncaught exception. Stopping the process...","logger":"org.apache.flink.runtime.util.FatalExitExceptionHandler","throwable":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalAccessError","msg":"class org.slf4j.MDC tried to access private field org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder.SINGLETON (org.slf4j.MDC and org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder are in unnamed module of loader 'app')","stack":["org.slf4j.MDC.(MDC.java:74)","akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.withMdc(Slf4jLogger.scala:98)","akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Slf4jLogger.scala:82)","akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)","akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.aroundReceive(Slf4jLogger.scala:54)","akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)","akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)","akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)","akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)","java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)","java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)","java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)"]}}

I have checked the stackoverflow and do not see any solution which is related to this. Can you help me?

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: You _probably_ have mismatched versions somewhere.

Comment: which dependency versions are you specifying?